# maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile)

Tags: java, maven, build

what's wrong? I don't understand.
I'm trying to do a multi module project, but I can't build the project due to this error.
I've searched this error also online but nothing useful. can anyone help me?

this is the log error:

```
maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project api: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: [ERROR] Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later. [ERROR] Target option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
```

this is my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>se.magnus.microservices.core.microservices-book</groupId>
    <artifactId>microservices-book</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>microservices-book</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <targetJdk>17</targetJdk>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>microservices</module>
        <module>api</module>
        <module>util</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

I have to build this multi module project

Answer (score 1):

by defualt maven compile with java 1.8 so you have to configure your maven plugin as follows adding this insiede your pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>se.magnus.microservices.core.microservices-book</groupId>
    <artifactId>microservices-book</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>microservices-book</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <targetJdk>17</targetJdk>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>microservices</module>
        <module>api</module>
        <module>util</module>
    </modules>

    <!-- add this --> 
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>17</source>
                        <target>17</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

that seemingly java compiler version error,try append this code in pom.xml and re-compiler

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.encoding>UTF-8</maven.compiler.encoding>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Comment: `java.version` works only if you use the spring-boot-parent... source/target should not be used with JDK9+ use `<maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>`. and the encoding is defined by the `project.build.sourceEncoding` so the `maven.compiler.encoding` is not required...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's easier than you think. You should define all plugins you are using that means the pluginManagement should contain all plugins (with their version). The most recent version can be found [here.](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>se.magnus.microservices.core.microservices-book</groupId>
    <artifactId>microservices-book</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>microservices-book</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>microservices</module>
        <module>api</module>
        <module>util</module>
    </modules>

    <!-- add this --> 
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.12.1</version>
                </plugin>
                 ..also define all other plugins hier as well!!!
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```